# Setting an image's width and height to different values based on responsiveness

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

I am using TailwindCSS 3.x to display an image as `h-9 sm:h-20` using TailWindCSS's utility classes based on responsiveness.

```
<img class="h-9 sm:h-20 rounded-full" src="path/image-1.webp" alt="img" />
```

I want to know if it's possible to achieve the same using img attributes width and height ?

For desktop I want it set as `width="80" height="80"`
For mobile I want it as `width="36" height="36"`

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. Because tailwind just work in `className`.

Tailwind CSS works by scanning all of your HTML, JavaScript components, and any other template files for `class names`, then generating all of the corresponding CSS for those styles.

In order for Tailwind to generate all of the CSS you need, you have to put your classes inside `class Name`.

[tailwind content-configuration doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add style classes based on your screen size.
I think `height` and `width` is in pixel.
`<img class="h-[36px] w-[36px] lg:h[80px] lg:w-[80px] rounded-full" src="path/image-1.webp" alt="img" />`

Here, I set `lg` is a breakpoint for desktop view. for more responsiveness you can [check here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-breakpoints)

Comment: I was looking for setting the width and height attributes of the img tag. The only way I found was to use detectmobilebrowsers.com's script and set it on the server-side.